# Windows phone store update app package on same app version?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I have uploaded an app with version 1.0.0.1. Now I want to just update the package of this submission and not version in Windows Phone store can i do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are updating the package, update the version, so users know that they have the latest version.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/gg442301(v=vs.105).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ff769509(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Is this necessary to update version or not. Just asking that can this be reason to reject the app in the store?

Comment: I am just asking this because there is no rejection criteria mentioned in Microsoft store for this. Is this a loop hole? As this can lead to wrong activity if my store account user name password is gotten into wrong hands.